# Getting an error message, please suggest

Tags: apt, package-management

The package system is broken...

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

apt-get install -f is not working. Please check the attached screen shots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAA0.png)

Comment: What command did you use in the first place? Have you tried `apt-get update` and apt-get `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: on sudo apt-get update

Comment: Have you tried apt-cdrom like stated in the Error log?